# Can I define a trait that has a generic function returning a trait object?

Tags: rust

Is it possible to have a trait function that returns any trait object?

Or, can a generic parameter be a trait object type?

```rust
trait ToVec<T> {
    fn to_vec(&self) -> Vec<&dyn T>;
}

trait TraitA {}
trait TraitB {}
// etc
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=92008c3e799f9c2f9189a0100daa4e1a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have `&dyn T`, as `T` is not a trait. But `&dyn ToVec<T>` (or `&dyn SomeOtherTrait`) is fine.

In your playground example, `Vec<T>` is actually correct because you already have `T` as a trait object `&dyn TraitA` in the `impl`s; but as the error message says, you need to fix lifetimes. E.g. [this compiles](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ad810d64524ccd630a90ac26ebccafc8)

```
trait TraitA {}

trait ToVec<T> {
    fn to_vec(&self) -> Vec<T>;
}

impl<'a, T: TraitA> ToVec<&'a dyn TraitA> for (&'a str, &'a T) {
    fn to_vec(&self) -> Vec<&'a dyn TraitA> {
        vec![
            self.1 as &dyn TraitA
        ]
    }
}
```

but may or may not be what you intended.

Comment: Your link is wrong FYI, looks like you copied the original link and didn't generate a new one.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Fixed, thank you (must have assumed it would regenerate after editing...).